# Having to choose between my validations/error messages or ordering things by another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'll try to explain this as well as possible, and I've spent a lot of time trying to make sure this wasn't a duplicate, but apologies if I've overlooked something. The issue I ran into is fairly straightforward, and it deals with the number of arguments I can pass `simple_fields_for` while working with nested attributes using cocoon. Without manually adding in some code to create the error notification, I wasn't getting anything out of it, so I had to set up code like so:

#### Course Model

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :learning_objectives, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :course
end
```

#### Learning Objective Model

```
class LearningObjective < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course, touch: true
  scope :sorted, -> { order(:sort) }
end
```

#### Form That Uses `f.error_notification`

```
= simple_form_for(@course) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .row
    .col-md-12 Learning Objectives
      = f.simple_fields_for :learning_objectives, f.error_notification do |objective|
        = render 'learning_objective_fields', f: objective
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Another Objective', f, :learning_objectives, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm', data: { association_insertion_node: '.objectives', association_insertion_method: :append }
```

#### Learning Objectives Partial

```
.nested-fields
  .table
    .row
      .col-md-8
        = f.input :name, label: false
      .col-md-2
        = f.input :sort
      .col-md-2.spaced-out
        =link_to_remove_association 'Remove Objective', f, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs'
```

And this works nicely to get the necessary notification on the nested field. However, I was previously using `f` in `simple_fields_for` like you see here:

#### Form That Uses `f.object.learning_objectives.order(:sort)`

```
= simple_form_for(@course) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .row
    .col-md-12 Learning Objectives
      = f.simple_fields_for :learning_objectives, f.object.learning_objectives.order(:sort) do |objective|
        = render 'learning_objective_fields', f: objective
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Another Objective', f, :learning_objectives, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm', data: { association_insertion_node: '.objectives', association_insertion_method: :append }
```

And when I remove that sorting, then it reverts back to the way it was originally sorting, which wasn't ideal. So the issue is that I can only utilize one of the arguments at a time, and I'm not sure if it's possible to have a method by which we may use more than one argument for our nested attributes' `f` object.

Perhaps there's a way to do this simply, and I'll also crosspost to stack overflow with the same title to see if they have a suggestions in case this is too specific to raise an issue here. Thanks so much for any advice or direction you could offer, and thanks for the great gem!

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. Unless I am confused, the second parameter for the simple_fields_for can only be the array of nested items, and if none given it will just check the relation/association. So I do not understand how passing f.error_notification (which is a visual representation of the errors) would work, unless the fields_for just skips it because it is a string and not an enumerable.

Secondly: if you call order it will attempt to order using sql, so it would indeed only show the stored items from the database. If you just try to sort the array it would just work as you would expect. E.g. something like

```
 f.object.learning_objectives.to_a.sort{|x,y| x.sort <=> y.sort}
```